# How to change/overwrite certain characters in a string?

Tags: string, bash, text

I've [written up](https://codeshare.io/sGInv) a 'hang-man' type game in bash. Which is currently working, but I just cannot get my head around on how to overwrite certain characters in the string.

So currently I get a letter (eg 'l') from the user and it checks it against a string 'hello' and prints out as ' _ _ l l _ ' ({is `$prev` in the code) I would like when the user enters 'e', the `$prev` to get updated to ' _ e l l _ ' and so on and so forth for 'h' and 'o'.

**Q:** How would I be able to change a certain character in a string?

Comment: Rather than holding your word in a *string*, since you are using bash, holding each character as an element of an array would allow you to index/change each character individually.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manipulate individual characters in a variable, then it is easier to hold all characters in an array. That way you can change the characters based on array index. Below shows a simple way to convert to/from an array while manipulating the characters. Note: there is no need to convert back to a variable, you can simply maintain the word being guessed at in an array:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a array

prev="__||_"    ## previous state of guessing
printf "%s\n" "$prev"

for ((i=0; i<${#prev}; i++)); do   ## convert to array
    array+=( ${prev:i:1} )
done

array[1]="e"                        ## update letter

## convert back to string
printf -v prev $(echo ${array[@]} | tr -d ' ')
printf "%s\n" "$prev"
```

**Output**

```
$ bash ~/scr/tmp/stack/strtoarray.sh
__||_
_e||_
```

Answer (score 0):

An implementation of hangman using arrays for the word and the answer.  It picks a random word from the file pointed to by ${words}.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

words='/usr/share/dict/words'

die() { >&2 echo $@; exit 1; }

join() { local IFS="$1"; shift; echo "$*"; }

new_word() {
  unset word
  local length=$(wc -l < ${words})
  local count=$((${RANDOM} % ${length}))
  head -${count} ${words} | tail -1 | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'
}

draw_hangman() {
  # draw hangman here
  ((++guesses))
}

[[ -f ${words} ]] || die "Missing words file: ${words}"

declare -i guesses=0
declare -a word=( $(new_word | grep -o .) )
declare -a answer=( $(printf '_ %.0s' $(seq 1 ${#word[@]})) )

while :; do
  echo -e "\nPress - to quit.\n"
  echo -e "${answer[@]}\n"
  read -s -n 1 -p "$((${#word[@]} - ${guesses})) more guesses: " guess
  echo
  [[ ${guess} == '-' ]] && echo && break # quit
  [[ ${guesses} -eq $((${#word[@]} - 1)) ]] && echo -e "\nYOU LOSE!\n" && \
    echo "The word was $(join '' ${word[@]})" && break
  [[ ${word[@]} != *${guess}* ]] && draw_hangman && continue
  for i in ${!word[@]}; do
    [[ ${word[${i}]} == ${guess} ]] && answer[${i}]=${guess}
  done
  [[ ${answer[@]} == ${word[@]} ]] && echo -e "\nYOU WIN!\n" && break
done
```